# Posso usare "quelli" per dire di parole che cominciano in st?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-choice

Ho un problema. La mia professoressa dice che dire "quelli stivali" è corretto. Dice che si può dire anche quegli stivali, ma io non sono sicuro, credo soltanto di "quegli stivali", e non "quelli stivali". Perchè stivali comincia con st, e non si può usare l'articolo "i". Si può usare quelli per dire quelli stivali?

Comment: È curioso, perché – non solo come ti hanno già risposto in italiano contemporaneo la forma corretta è “quegli stivali” – ma “quelli” oggi non è proprio una forma dell'aggettivo dimostrativo “quello” (le cui forme al plurale, a seconda dell'iniziale della parola successiva, sono “quei” e “quegli”). “Quelli” è solo una forma del pronome: “Questi stivali sono vecchi, mentre quelli sono nuovi”.

Comment: @DaG non ci avevo pensato. Infatti dipende dal contesto e dalla frase. La mia risposta riguarda il caso generale

Comment: È un errore grave scrivere "quelli stivali", la tua insegnante ha torto.

Comment: @Fede: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/2127).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La tua professoressa ha torto (almeno per quanto riguarda l'italiano contemporaneo), devi usare **quegli** davanti alla parola stivali ed, in generale, davanti a tutte le parole che iniziano per ***gn, ps, pn, z, x, y, s + consonante***.

La regola si applica a partire dall'articolo determinativo **lo**, vale anche per il plurale **gli** e si può estendere all'aggettivo dimostrativo **quegli**.

Ad esempio:

- quegli **gn**occhi
- quegli **ps**icologi
- quegli **pn**eumatici
- quegli **z**aini
- quegli **x**ilofoni
- quegli **y**ogurt
- quegli **sp**aventapasseri, quegli **st**udi, quegli **sc**iocchi...

[Qui puoi trovare ulteriori informazioni riguardanti l'uso dell'articolo determinativo in generale](http://aulalingue.scuola.zanichelli.it/benvenuti/2009/11/26/uso-dellarticolo-determinativo/).

Comment: Tutto giustissimo, e aggiungo solo che la risposta vale per l'italiano contemporaneo: in altri tempi la flessione di “quello” era più elastica. Per esempio, il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/quello/) riporta forme come “quello corpo, quelli denari, quegli frati”; per un esempio ottocentesco di “quelli stivali” si veda [qui](https://books.google.it/books?id=PEQIrMAGDOMC&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179&dq=%22quelli+stivali%22&source=bl&ots=1zVO9YQkc1&sig=mnOWLAyah1Wv9fK9vG45b4gVLxk&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22quelli%20stivali%22&f=false).

Comment: @DaG Ho aggiunto alla risposta la tua precisazione, grazie

Comment: Aggiungerei anche le parole che cominciano per vocale.